# Android Studio 0.8.6 Gradle project refresh failed, connection reset

Tags: connection, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

so, I've looked all over for a solution to this, and can't find one anywhere.

Basically, when I open my project, Android Studio wants to sync the project by downloading Gradle and what not. No matter what I do, I always get: Gradle 'myapp' project refresh failed, Error: Connection reset.

I'm not behind a proxy, my connection is fine. I've downloaded the gradle files manually but AS still wont sync because no cache exists, understandably.

I had this problem in AS 0.8.0 as well, thought maybe updating might fix something.

My build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hiddensignal.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Gradle wrapper:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

another build.gradle from myapplication:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

These are all default values, which I assume should work.

I've tried pretty much everything. Not sure if it's related, but I can't add new activities into my project, the drop down list is completely grayed out with a note that says (requires minSdk >= 7) on each of the items in the drop down menu.

I'm tempted to downgrade AS in the hopes that an earlier version might finally connect and download the dependencies it needs, but I have doubts about that working.

Does anyone see anything that could possibly be wrong with my files there? I've gone through countless threads and I've tried changing the repository, the dependencies, reimporting my project, etc...

Any advice on what else I could try? I'm not behind any firewalls, SDK is fully updated. I have no idea what to do next, I'd really like to continue using AS but I might have to go back to Eclipse at this rate.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Tried doing Build > Clean, got this error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download artifact 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2:gradle.jar'
      > Connection reset
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `mavenCentral()` inside the `buildscript.repositories` enclosure, like so.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()   // This repo should have the gradle plugin
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }
```

Comment: I've tried it, it didn't work. Not sure if it'll make a difference, but I'm going to try updating at a friends house, I doubt it'll be any different though.

Comment: @Chris - I've added a second answer which might be of use

Comment: Thanks! i solved my problem "Error connect reset" on gradle sync proyect

Answer (score 1):

My `distributionUrl` is different.

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-bin.zip`

It has a secure connection, maybe try `https` instead of just `http` - that sounds like a likely cause.

If that fails, try `1.12-bin.zip` at the end.

Comment: I thought it was working for a sec after adding the s, but alas, in the end, no matter what combination of http, https, 1.12-bin.zip and 1.12-all.zip I use, it comes back with connection reset. I appreciate the help but it looks like nothing I do will work.

Comment: Just to check: Did you keep in `mavenCentral()` when you tried with the `s`?

Comment: I did. I'll try it without it and report back.

Comment: @Chris - did you ever get this fixed? Try placing the `buildscript` closure in the root `build.gradle` inside the `allprojects` closure.

Comment: Never got it fixed, tried putting the buildscript closure in the allprojects closure and at least I'm getting a new error:

"Error:(15, 0) You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!"
when I Jump to Source it points to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
For me I just need to configure proxy settings again in File\Settings\HTTP Proxy.
And please check your firewall.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved it with changing support library line to this:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on company VPN, wasn't sure about their firewall settings but after disconnecting from their network I was able to update/connect. Hope that helps.